# Deep eager macroexpansion

Tags: elisp, elisp-macros, clojure, eval, require

This works:

```
(require 'clojure-mode)
(when (member 'clojure-mode my-packages)
  (define-clojure-indent
    (-> 1)
    (->> 1)))
```

This gives the error `Wrong type argument: listp, 1`:

```
(when (member 'clojure-mode my-packages)
  (require 'clojure-mode)
  (define-clojure-indent
    (-> 1)
    (->> 1)))
```

Here's what I think is happening in the second version:

1. `define-clojure-indent` is a macro [defined by `clojure-mode`](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode#indentation-of-macro-forms), which is not loaded by default. So `define-clojure-indent` is only defined after `(require 'clojure-mode)` is evaluated.
2. Since both the `require` and the `define-clojure-indent` call are in the same top-level form, all macroexpansion happens before any evaluation happens. This appears to be similar to the [Gilardi scenario](https://technomancy.us/143) from Clojure.
3. Both `->` and `->>` are macros [defined by `dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#--x-optional-form-rest-more), which I also had loaded. They have the behavior that both of the forms `(-> 1)` and `(->> 1)` expand to just `1`.
4. It appears that since Emacs does its macroexpansion on the `define-clojure-indent` form before it has loaded `clojure-mode`, it does not yet know that `define-clojure-indent` is actually a macro. Therefore, it goes ahead and macroexpands *recursively*, transforming

   ```
   (define-clojure-indent
     (-> 1)
     (->> 1))
   ```

   to

   ```
   (define-clojure-indent
     1
     1)
   ```

   by interpreting `->` and `->>` as macros instead of simply unevaluated symbols.
5. When `clojure-mode` is actually loaded and `define-clojure-indent` is invoked as a macro, it throws an error because it expects its arguments to be lists, not integers.

Whereas in the first version, since the `require` and `define-clojure-indent` are in different top-level forms, by the time Emacs gets to macroexpanding the `define-clojure-indent` form, it already knows that `define-clojure-indent` is a macro, and doesn't try to do macroexpansion on its arguments. So `(-> 1)` and `(->> 1)` are passed to `define-clojure-indent` as lists of symbols, as I would expect, and everything works.

So here is my question. If Emacs doesn't know whether or not something is a macro, *why would it do macroexpansion on the arguments*? In this situation, it clearly produces unintended behavior. As far as I know, this would never happen in the Clojure macro system. And I can't think of any situation in which the current functionality would be desired.

Surely I am missing something here. Is there an elegant way to avoid this problem? Or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding?

*(P.S. I am aware that I could use `eval-after-load`. The same problem still occurs, but I used `require` in the example because it was simpler. Full code—obviously not yet working, because of this and other errors—available [here](https://github.com/raxod502/dotfiles/blob/4a6d31edef74bdc208b1c47fbd655e37800aca5b/init.el#L453).)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Stefan explained *why* you see what you see: Your `require` statement is not at top level of the file.

A *solution* to the byte-compiler not evaluating your (non top-level) `require` statement is to force its evaluation, using **`(eval-and-compile (require 'clojure-mode))`**.

The fact that `require` is evaluated by the byte-compiler when it is at top level is pointed out in the Elisp manual, node [Named Features](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html) (which I found by using **`i require`** in the manual).  There you see this:

> When `require` is used at top level in a file, it takes effect when
>   you byte-compile that file (*note Byte Compilation::) as well as when
>   you load it.  This is in case the required package contains macros that
>   the byte compiler must know about.  It also avoids byte compiler
>   warnings for functions and variables defined in the file loaded with
>   `require`.

Answer (score 7):

`(require <foo>)` is treated specially when it's at top-level (it causes the compiler to require the file also, rather than only do the require at run-time).

If the `require` is not performed at compilation time, then your code can't be compiled properly since the `define-clojure-indent` macro won't be known during compilation, leading to mis-compilation, indeed.

If the byte-compiler never macro-expanded calls in args to something that is not known to be a function, then lots of existing code would break: all the warnings like `function <foo> is not known to be defined` would turn into compilation errors.  We could do that, but lots of existing files would then fail to compile.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Is there a reason macro-expansion can't be deferred until runtime if some symbols can't be resolved at compile time? It seems to me that the current behavior is "overly eager" macro-expansion, and making the compiler not **insist** on expanding all macros at compile time could fix situations like the one in my question without breaking existing code.

Comment: You can't compile code which has not yet been macro-expanded.  So deferring macro-expansion implies deferring compilation.